# HAProxy check does not check content on IIS

Tags: iis, haproxy, healthcheck

I am new to HAproxy and I have read the docs googled every possible phrase I could think of but I cannot get haproxy to read the content my test page returns.

Here's the setup:
Single arm config - 
1x CentOS 7 haproxy 1.5.14 -
2x Windows Server 2012r2 IIS 8.5

Backend Server config:

```
backend mt-http
balance     roundrobin
mode http
option httpchk /check.aspx?appserver=dev-cluster.xxxx.com&databaseserver=test.xxxx.com&database=######dev
http-check expect string 200\ OK
server  WebLB-test2 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check
server  WebLB-test1 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check
```

check.aspx connects to a specific database through a named app server cluster to confirm end to end connectivity from the web server through database.  If the test is successful the check returns 200 OK in a web page as text. If one of the components is unavailable check.aspx returns a 500 error. 
Success:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head><title>
        Mediatools Check
 </title></head>
 <body id="bodyID">200 OK</body>
 </html>
```

Fail:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head><title>
     Mediatools Check
 </title></head>
 <body id="bodyID">500 Internal Server Error</body>
 </html>
```

When I use the option "http-check expect string 200\ OK" (I have tried with and with out the "\" escape character in the string) the servers show down and the error is "Layer 7 Invalid Response: http content check found empty response body."

When I use the option "http-check expect status 200 OK", the return page is successful whether the status text is 200 or not (because I assume, the return of check.aspx is successful even if returns 500 code).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the output from a curl -v:
Looks like maybe my request is too long?

```
 curl -v xx.xx.xx.xx/yourDB/check.aspx?appserver=dev-cluster.yourdomain.com&databaserver=test.yourdomain.com&database=yourDBdev
 [1] 16077
 [2] 16078
 [root@dev-cluster log]# * About to connect() to xx.xx.xx.xx port 80 (#0)
 *   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
 * Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
 > GET /customer/check.aspx?appserver=dev-cluster.yourdomain.com HTTP/1.1
 > User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
 > Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
 > Accept: */*
 > 
 < HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 < Cache-Control: private
 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 < Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
 < X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 < X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
 < Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 22:16:59 GMT
 < Content-Length: 3428
 < 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Runtime Error</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
     pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
     .version {color: gray;}
     .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
     .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
     @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
      pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
     }
     @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
      pre { width: 280px; }
     }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

        <span><H1>Server Error in '/customer' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
        <br><br>

        <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code><pre>

 &lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

  &lt;configuration&gt;
  &lt;system.web&gt;
    &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/system.web&gt;
 &lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

        <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code><pre>

 &lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

 &lt;configuration&gt;
 &lt;system.web&gt;
    &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/system.web&gt;
 &lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

</body>
 </html>
  * Connection #0 to host xx.xx.xx.xx left intact

 [1]-  Done                    curl -v xx.xx.xx.xx/customer/check.aspx?appserver=dev-cluster.yourdomain.com
 [2]+  Done                    databaserver=test.yourdomain.com
```

Okay one more time!
I had the Web developer pull the appserver, databaseserver, and database parameter from the web.config instead of sending them to the check.aspx

The new config looks like this:

```
 backend mt-http
 balance     roundrobin
 mode http
 option httpchk GET /customer/check.aspx
 http-check expect status 200 OK
 server  WebLB-test2 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check
 server  WebLB-test1 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check
```

New Return from Curl:

```
 curl -v xx.xx.xx.xx/pgglobal/check.aspx
 * About to connect() to xx.xx.xx.xx port 80 (#0)
 *   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
 * Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
 > GET /customer/check.aspx HTTP/1.1
 > User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
 > Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
 > Accept: */*
 > 
 < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 < Cache-Control: private
 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 < Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
 < Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=whvmaboyg03lsl3rd1gcsbxl; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
 < X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 < X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
 < Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 23:00:07 GMT
 < Content-Length: 162
 < 


 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head><title>
Happiness Check
 </title></head>
 <body id="bodyID">Success</body>
 </html>
 * Connection #0 to host xx.xx.xx.xx left intact
```

haproxy still reports "Layer 7 wrong status: HTTP status check returned <500>"

Here is the curl output on a failed check.aspx (one of the components checked is powered off to force the error page).

```
 curl -v xx.xx.xx.xx/Customer/check.aspx
 * About to connect() to xx.xx.xx.xx port 80 (#0)
 *   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
 * Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
 > GET /Customer/check.aspx HTTP/1.1
 > User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
 > Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
 > Accept: */*
 > 
 < HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 < Cache-Control: private
 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 < Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
 < X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 < X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
 < Date: Thu, 18 Feb 2016 17:17:01 GMT
 < Content-Length: 3428
 < 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Runtime Error</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
     body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
     p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
     H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
     pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
     .version {color: gray;}
     .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
     .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
     @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
      pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
     }
     @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
      pre { width: 280px; }
     }
    </style>
 </head>

 <body bgcolor="white">

        <span><H1>Server Error in '/Customer' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
        <br><br>

        <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code><pre>

 &lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

 &lt;configuration&gt;
  &lt;system.web&gt;
    &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
  &lt;/system.web&gt;
 &lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

        <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>

        <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <code><pre>

 &lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

 &lt;configuration&gt;
  &lt;system.web&gt;
    &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
  &lt;/system.web&gt;
 &lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

  </body>
 </html>
 * Connection #0 to host xx.xx.xx.xx left intact
```

Answer (score 2):

Your config is perfect, except for one little thing. You haven't specified that the health check should actually fetch the page it's requesting, and as a result the contents will be blank.

According to the HAProxy [docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#option%20httpchk), `option httpchk` by default uses the `OPTIONS` method, which doesn't get the body of the page.

> option httpchk <uri>
>   option httpchk <method> <uri>
>   option httpchk <method> <uri> <version>
>
> Enable HTTP protocol to check on the servers health
>
> **<method>**
>   is the optional HTTP method used with the requests. When not set, the "OPTIONS" method is used, as it generally requires low server processing and is easy to filter out from the logs. Any method may be used, though it is not recommended to invent non-standard ones.
>
> **<uri>**
>   is the URI referenced in the HTTP requests. It defaults to " / " which is accessible by default on almost any server, but may be changed to any other URI. Query strings are permitted.
>
> **<version>**
>   is the optional HTTP version string. It defaults to "HTTP/1.0" but some servers might behave incorrectly in HTTP 1.0, so turning it to HTTP/1.1 may sometimes help. Note that the Host field is mandatory in HTTP/1.1, and as a trick, it is possible to pass it after "\r\n" following the version string.

You have a couple of options to solve this.

1. You can change your method to `GET`:

   ```
   backend mt-http
     balance roundrobin
     mode http
     option httpchk GET /check.aspx?appserver=dev-cluster.xxxx.com&databaseserver=test.xxxx.com&database=######dev
     http-check expect string 200\ OK
     server  WebLB-test2 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check
     server  WebLB-test1 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check
   ```

   I've tried this on my test load-balancer and it works as expected.
2. You can change `check.aspx` to emit something other than a `200 OK` HTTP status when the checks fail.
   I had once had a need to check whether a particular service was running, because IIS would always return `200 OK` even if the actual application was down on a backend. So I wrote a simple C# script to do just that:

   ```
   <%@ Page Language="C#"%>
   <%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
   <%@ Import Namespace="System.ServiceProcess" %>
   <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
   <%  

   ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(Request.QueryString["service"]);

   switch (sc.Status)
   {
     case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
       Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
       Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
       Response.Write("Running");
       break;

     default:
       Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
       Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
       Response.Write("Failed");
       break;
   }
   %>
   ```

   You'd use it thusly:

   ```
   backend FooBar
     balance roundrobin
     mode http
     option httpchk GET /ServiceCheck/check.aspx?service=ServiceName
     http-check expect status 200
     server  WebLB-test2 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check
     server  WebLB-test1 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check
   ```

Comment: You can use `http-check expect status 200` without `GET` specified because that's in the headers, thus it doesn't matter if there's no body. If you want to check the *body* of the response for a particular string, you'll need to specify the method used for the HTTP check.

Comment: I got it.  That's what I was looking for.  Sorry I misunderstood what you were saying originally

Comment: I tried changing the method and now, I receive Layer 7 invalid response: HTTP Content check did not match.  I tried just the 200 or just the OK, I've tried rstring and each combination.  Now when I try to do expect status I receive HTTP status returned <500>.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Also, when the check.aspx fails it returns the error code (Usually 500) in the page (as shown above). So I'm not sure how your 2nd suggestion is different than what I'm trying currently doing, It would appear though that content in the body is not my friend.  I am grateful for the help on this!

Comment: The 2nd suggestion says that the check page should return something other than a 200 *HTTP status*, the body can be anything you want, including having the 500 there too. Can you update your question to include the output of a verbose `curl` request for each situation (up and down)?

Comment: I see. . . I'll try to get a curl output (not exactly sure how to do that but I'm sure the googs can tell me).  Thanks!

Comment: I see your `curl` outputs, which is good. You could have fixed the first run by enclosing your URL in single quotes, but having the dev pull the connection details from the web.config is actually a good idea. In any event, can you also post a `curl` output of what a *failed* check would look like?